# how to add space between views in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, alignment, android-relativelayout

How can I add spaces between views in `RelativeLayout` group?

I was trying to add a space between `TextView` and `Button` after aligning the `TextView` at the top of `Button` using `Layout_marginBottom` and `paddingBottom`  but non of them worked.

here is the code:

```
<TextView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:text=" Drawing ... "
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/reset"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="reset"
    android:text="Reset" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text=" Drawing ... "
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="reset"
    android:text="Reset"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```